# Where does Groove Music store playlists?

Tags: windows-10, metadata, playlists, groove-music

I've set up a clean installation of windows 10 but i have my old disk image backed up, I restored all the music by simply adding their folders back but I also want my playlists, anyone knows where does Groove music keep their files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groove music stores playlists under:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Packages\[Microsoft.ZuneMusic_xxxxxxxxxxxxx]\LocalState\Playlists
```

Please note that they might take some time to get recognised, that is if they get recognised at all. especially if they are defined by their metadata rather than their location on the disk.
As you see here It managed to relink just 3 songs out of 14.

[image: Only 3 songs are correctly recovered]

You can tell which is defined by which by editing the playlist file using any text editor...
this how a metadata defined music file looks like (less likely to be recovered):

```
<media albumTitle="XXXXXX" albumArtist="XXXXXX" trackTitle="XXXXXX" trackArtist="XXXXXX" duration="#####" />
```

and this is how a source-location defined music file looks like (more likely to be recovered):

```
media src="X:\Music\XXXX\0#. XXXXXX.xxx" albumTitle="XXXX" albumArtist="XXXX" trackTitle="XXXX" trackArtist="XXXX" duration="######" />
```

If you are unable to recover them, at least you have the songs names list to remake it from scratch.