# How to transfer Groove playlist to another computer with the same library?

Tags: windows, file-transfer, music, export, groove-music

I have two computers with identical local music libraries; how do I transfer a playlist from one to the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually answered here:
[Where does Groove Music store playlists?](https://superuser.com/questions/1584829/where-does-groove-music-store-playlists)

(It is in this folder: C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Packages\[Microsoft.ZuneMusic_xxxxxxxxxxxxx]\LocalState\Playlists)

Answer (score 1):

Groove playlists are files with extensions [zpl](https://fileinfo.com/extension/zpl). You can normally locate them on the `C:\Users\Username\Music\Playlists` (replace `Username` with your/the user name). Copy them from the 1st PC to the same folder on the 2nd PC.

Comment: And if they aren't located there?

Comment: @maxbear123 Then you need to find were you saved/moved them. I have just done a quick test, and the playlist I have created is in the mentioned folder.